# Google Apps Script using installed trigger won't call another function

Tags: google-apps-script, eventtrigger

I have a supposedly very simple piece of code that I can't get to work
`
I've verified that when I choose the transaction type on the Summary sheet, it passes correctly into the chooseTransaction function as either "Income" or "Expense". I've verified that the insertIncomeTransaction and insertExpenseTransaction functions work, i previously had them tied to buttons, but I wanted to switch to dropdown so my sheet would work for mobile too. The script just won't call the functions based on the input.

```
function chooseTransaction(e) {
  console.log("e.value:", e.value);
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === "Summary!B11") {

    if (e.value === "Income") {
      insertIncomeTransaction();
    } else if (e.value === "Expense") {
      insertExpenseTransaction();
    }
  }

  e.range.setValue("Add Transaction");
}
```

Comment: What trigger are you using?

Comment: What does it's event object look like?

Comment: I believer the problem is `.getA1Notation()` only returns the range `B11` without the sheet name.  You will have to check the sheet name too.